# Как склонировать отдельную папку с гит репозитория?

Tags: git

Есть папка https://github.com/LineageOS/android_frameworks_base/tree/cm-13.0/packages/SystemUI. Как мне только ее склонировать именно по этой ветке?

Comment: Так не получается? git clone https://github.com/LineageOS/android_frameworks_base/tree/cm-13.0/packages/SystemUI

Comment: или вот так можно, если не все нужно, а отдельные файлы goo.gl/ytyTRc

Comment: склонируйте всё и удалите ненужное. в чём задача-то состоит? чтобы меньше трафика потратить? насколько я знаю, сэкономить трафик, увы, не получится: скачивается хранилище, т.е. [**объекты**](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-Git), а не какие-то там «файлы/каталоги».